stuck on proof (help with intuition): set $A$ is open $\iff A$ complement is closed
So to prove $"\implies "$ I go by contradiction:

Let $A$ be open and $A^c$ (the complement of $A$) also be open.
since $A^c$ is open it does not contain its limit points.
let $y$ be a limit point of $A^c$, then  $y \in (A^c)^c =A$.
since $y$ is a limit point of $A$ complement there must always be an element of $A$ complement in any epsilon ball around $y$.
But the thing is that A is open: which means any point in a is interior (that is for any point in a, there is a ball around that point that is entirely contained in A)
since $y$ is in $A$, this should have been the case for y too.
But we see that there is no ball around $y$ which does not contain an element of $A^c$.
contradiction: 7) is contradicting 5) & 6) [end of proof $"\implies "$]

*** The other direction though is tricky:
I want to go by contradiction again: I say

By contradiction let $A^c$ be closed and $A$ also be closed.
Since $A$ is closed it contains all its limit points.
...*** at this point my brain just stops "seeing" what's up [I can probably look this up but I learn better by discussing stuff so any help is appreciated].


Perhaps state definition of "open" and "closed".  If you ask this question, I assume the definition of "$B$ is closed" would not be "complement of $B$ is open", but something else.

Also, please use MathJax.

The claim that an open set does not contain its limit points is wrong.

I'm assuming that what you meant by "closed" is that it contains all of its limit points, while by "open", you meant that a subset $X$ of a space (which I believe in this case is $\mathbb{R}^n$, but honestly, any metric space will do) is open if and only if for any $x\in X$ there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon (x) \subseteq X$.
Next time, if you will use notions that need defining, please explicitly state them.
So, I see that you have a mistake in the proof. By saying " $A$ is open and $A^C$ is also open," you basically said that not closed $\equiv$ open, but this is not true. The simplest counterexample is the empty set. Otherwise, your proof of that direction is correct. Simply replace "also open" with "not closed".
As for your attempt for the backward direction, you again assumed that not open is closed (or not closed is open), but again, this is false.
Instead, here is a possible proof sketch:
Consider a set $A$ such that $A^C$ is closed. By way of contradiction, suppose $A$ is not open.
Then, use the negation of the definition of "open sets" to show that an element of $A^C$ exists in $A$, a contradiction.
Thus, $A$ is open.
$Q.E.D.$
